# Fail callback called although Ajax request is performed and server returns 200 with data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, cache-manifest

I have a HTML5 test webpage `test.html` with a cache manifest. The webpage does an Ajax request to the same server, to a webpage `do_get_data.php` that is listed under the section `NETWORK:` in the cache manifest.

The request is performed by both Firefox 10 and iPhone iOS 5 Safari (this is logged in the serving PHP script `do_get_data.php`). Firefox 10 calls the `success` callback function after 10 seconds, that is, when data from the server is returned. However, my iPhone iOS 5 Safari calls the `fail` callback function immediately after it started the request and doesn't call the `success` callback function.

For iPhone iOS 5 Safari, the `textStatus` is `error` and `JSON.stringify(jqXHR)` is `{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}`.

The request is performed using the following code in `test.html`:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test_ok(data) {
        alert('Test OK, data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    }
    function testFail(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert(textStatus + ' | ' + JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
    }
    function get_data(testurl) {
        var senddata, request;
        alert('Request for ' + testurl + ' started.');
        window.testid = new Date().getTime();
        senddata = {
            background: true,
            requestId: window.testid
        };
        request = $.ajax({
            url: testurl,
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            data: senddata,
            success: test_ok
        });
        request.fail(testFail);
    }
</script>
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="get_data('do_get_data.php')" value="test sending" />
```

For reference, `do_get_data.php` looks like this:

```php
<?php
    $id = md5(rand() . rand());
    trigger_error(implode("\t", array('start', $id, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $_SERVER['USER_AGENT']));
    sleep(10);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $json = json_encode(array('msg'=>'Test was OK'));
    trigger_error(implode("\t", array('echo', $id, $json));
    echo $json;
?>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove sleep(10) ?

Comment: And do I understand it correctly that you have a log that shows successful requests from Safari on the server side?

Comment: @asaddude Even if I remove sleep(10), the situation is the same. Yes, the log on the server side shows Safari.

Comment: I see you use a hybrid definition of AJAX callbacks - new way (`jqXHR.fail()`) and the old way (`success` option of `$.ajax()`). Is there a particular reason for the combination? Does it yield same results when `jqXHR.done()` or `error` option respectively is used instead?

Comment: @Petr There is no good reason for the combination. However, `done()` or `error` option do unfortunately not change the fact that it works in Firefox but not iOS 5 Safari.

Comment: OK. To narrow it down more, and I realize the following wouldn't be a "solution", but what happens if you disable the manifest?

Comment: @Petr Vostrel It is not an optimal solution, but it DOES work when disabling the manifest and is an okay workaround until I find the real culprit.

Answer (score 2):

I've been given to understand, that causes of status code 0 are (1) loading from `file://`, (2) unreachable network resource and (3) cross domain policy. Since you load PHP, we can safely rule number 1 and since your server logs Safari also the number 2 too, which leaves us with 3. Does all of the above code sit on the same domain? If not, use the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` HTTP header in the PHP to allow cross domain requests.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.org')
```

Also, you should make sure, the click on the button input performs only the `onclick` and not any other default behavior (whatever that may be on the iOS). Returning `false` from the `onclick` handler would prevent it:

```
<input type="button" onclick="get_data('do_get_data.php'); return false" ... />
```

**UPDATE:**

As a last resort you can always simply disable the cache manifest to move its maybe buggy implementation out of the way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I like your reasoning. Theoretically, I agree it might be a cross domain policy problem. However, it is on the very same domain. `http://` is not even used for the URL, but instead `do_get_data.php` without any domain name. Is there a good way to debug this problem? Returning false did actually not change anything.

Comment: Unfortunately, the debugging facilities are very poor on iOS and mobile devices in general... When doing my research, I also stumbled onto related mentions, where relative path was identified as the cause. Have you tried absolute URL path? And to clarify - does the problem persist without the cache manifest?

Comment: However, using disabling the manifest as you proposed in your earlier comment. This is an okay workaround until I find the real culprit. I will give you the bounty provided no one else solves the main problem, if you just copy your comment to a new answer, or including your comment in this answer.

Comment: @Richard86 I've updated the answer and I'm happy it kills the pain for  you. However, since we have it somehow isolated now, out of curiosity, how does your cache manifest look like?

Answer (score 2):

I have struggled with this for a while and the answer was in the bug report answers:

use

NETWORK:
*

in the cache manifest to avoid caching the ajax request too.

Answer (score 1):

What if you change your `$.ajax` call to

```
$.ajax({
    url: testurl,
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    data: senddata
}).then(
    function(result) { test_ok(result); },
    function(result) { testFail(result); }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem. It still results in a request, but `testFail()` is called.

Comment: What happens if you remove the Content-Type header in your PHP code?  Maybe Safari is having an issue with that.  In all the AJAX code I've ever written, I've never set a Content-Type header.  I just echo the plain text.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you are running your site under iOS, but there's been an issue with jQuery and AJAX requests while using manifest files: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8412

Although you are already listing the resource under the NETWORK section of the manifest, I would suggest trying out the other workaround listed there:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
  isLocal: true
});
```

Comment: Thank you for new thoughts on the problem. It seems that the ticket actually returns the correct content, which is not the case for me. The request is actually done live to the server. I tried with `isLocal: true` but unfortunately this did not solve the problem. The same error exists.